# httpwebrequest getting content type tex/plain instead of x-rar-compressed

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I have some issues downloading protected files. Here is my code:

```
request = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite.com/test.rar")
request.CookieContainer = logincookie
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 Java/1.7.0"
request.Method = "GET"
response = request.GetResponse()
If Not response.ContentType = "application/x-rar-compressed" Then
MsgBox("Error: " & ErrorToString() & vbCrLf & "Current file name is : " & response.ContentType.ToString)
Exit Sub
End If
```

I have done authorization before and use the same cookies to download file. And response is giving back for me content type text/plain. I tried to read response and show in webrowser and i`ve got something hieroglyphs "Rar!ϐs +t@�C ��%/�B3........"

I tried to stram any txt file, it read without any problem and showed me text inside it.

Does anybody know what can cause this issue?

Comment: Looks like the web server isn't configured for the "rar" file extension. Have you checked the web server configuration?

Comment: Yeah, I think server is not configured. I am not able to configure it now, need to wait. I try now same thing but swith zip and it recognizes zip :) Thanks :)